# Как добавить в таблицу Sql подкатегории

Tags: sql, база-данных

проблема такая, есть таблица категорий в приложении Android, эти категории управляются админ панелью, как добавить в эти категории под категории, если не трудно разжуйте, а то я не очень понимаю.

код с файла sql

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_category` (

  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  `category_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL

)
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Да как и обычно создаётся связанные таблицы.

Нужно создать таблицу `tbl_subcategory`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_subcategory` (

  `subcategory_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

  `subcategory_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  `subcategory_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL

)
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

и добавить колонку `subcategory_id` в таблицу `tbl_category`

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_category ADD subcategory_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

CONSTRAINT добавите если надо.

**PS**

Обычно людей путает слово **под** в некоторых словах думая что это что-то ниже, когда на самом деле в иерархии оно выше (появляется раньше). Категорий не может быть без **под**категорий, а подкатегории могут спокойно быть без категорий. (Примеры с последующим заполнением, nullable ... и прочий тому подобное не рассматривать в данной ситуации речь не о том)

Comment: не совсем понял куда вставлять но всё равно спасибо большое, буду решать.